# No data is displayed on the page. Why might this be happening?(Php/Yii2)

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

This is part of DebtController.php which should take data from database

```
public function actionCurrent()
    {
        $userId = Yii::$app->user->id;
        $debtData = Debt::find()
            ->select([
                'currency_id',
                'depositConfirmedAmount' => 'IF((to_user_id = ' . $userId . ') && (status = ' . Debt::STATUS_CONFIRM . '), amount, 0)',
                'creditConfirmedAmount' => 'IF((from_user_id = ' . $userId . ') && (status = ' . Debt::STATUS_CONFIRM . '), amount, 0)',
            ])
            ->andWhere([
                'OR',
                ['from_user_id' => $userId],
                ['to_user_id' => $userId]
            ]);
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Debt::find()
                ->from(['debtData' => $debtData])
                ->select([
                    'currency_id',
                    'depositConfirmed' => 'SUM(debtData.depositConfirmedAmount)',
                    'creditConfirmed' => 'SUM(debtData.creditConfirmedAmount)',
                ])
                ->groupBy(['currency_id']),
        ]);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

        ]);
    }
```

This part does not output data in index.php.
This is the table to which the data should be output.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                        'summary' => false,
                        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-hover'],
                        'columns' => [
                            [
                                'label' => 'Currency',
                                'value' => function (Debt $data) {
                                    return $data->currency->code ?? null;
                                },
                                'format' => 'html',
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => 'My Deposits',
                                'value' => function (Debt $data) {
                                    $text = $data->depositConfirmed;
                                    return Html::a($text, ['/debt/view', 'direction' => Debt::DIRECTION_DEPOSIT, 'currencyId' => $data->currency_id]);
                                },
                                'format' => 'html',
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => 'My Credits',
                                'value' => function (Debt $data) {
                                    $text = $data->creditConfirmed;
                                    return Html::a($text, ['/debt/view', 'direction' => Debt::DIRECTION_CREDIT, 'currencyId' => $data->currency_id]);
                                },
                                'format' => 'html',
                            ],
                        ]
```

If I vardump $dataProvider it print that.
This is an edited note that may help you with this issue.

```
object(yii\data\ActiveDataProvider)#172 (12) {
  ["query"]=>
  object(app\models\queries\DebtQuery)#177 (33) {
    ["sql"]=>
    NULL
    ["on"]=>
    NULL
    ["joinWith"]=>
    NULL
    ["select"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["currency_id"]=>
      string(11) "currency_id"
      ["depositConfirmed"]=>
      string(36) "SUM(debtData.depositConfirmedAmount)"
      ["creditConfirmed"]=>
      string(35) "SUM(debtData.creditConfirmedAmount)"
    }
    ["selectOption"]=>
    NULL
    ["distinct"]=>
    NULL
    ["from"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["debtData"]=>
      object(app\models\queries\DebtQuery)#164 (33) {
        ["sql"]=>
        NULL
        ["on"]=>
        NULL
        ["joinWith"]=>
        NULL
        ["select"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["currency_id"]=>
          string(11) "currency_id"
          ["depositConfirmedAmount"]=>
          string(49) "IF(((to_user_id = 1) && (status = 1)), amount, 0)"
          ["creditConfirmedAmount"]=>
          string(51) "IF(((from_user_id = 1) && (status = 1)), amount, 0)"
        }
        ["selectOption"]=>
        NULL
        ["distinct"]=>
        NULL
        ["from"]=>
        NULL
        ["groupBy"]=>
        NULL
        ["join"]=>
        NULL
        ["having"]=>
        NULL
        ["union"]=>
        NULL
        ["withQueries"]=>
        NULL
        ["params"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["queryCacheDuration"]=>
        NULL
        ["queryCacheDependency"]=>
        NULL
        ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
        array(0) {
        }
        ["where"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(2) "OR"
          [1]=>
          array(1) {
            ["from_user_id"]=>
            int(1)
          }
          [2]=>
          array(1) {
            ["to_user_id"]=>
            int(1)
          }
        }
        ["limit"]=>
        NULL
        ["offset"]=>
        NULL
        ["orderBy"]=>
        NULL
        ["indexBy"]=>
        NULL
        ["emulateExecution"]=>
        bool(false)
        ["modelClass"]=>
        string(15) "app\models\Debt"
        ["with"]=>
        NULL
        ["asArray"]=>
        NULL
        ["multiple"]=>
        NULL
        ["primaryModel"]=>
        NULL
        ["link"]=>
        NULL
        ["via"]=>
        NULL
        ["inverseOf"]=>
        NULL
        ["viaMap":"yii\db\ActiveQuery":private]=>
        NULL
      }
    }
    ["groupBy"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "currency_id"
    }
    ["join"]=>
    NULL
    ["having"]=>
    NULL
    ["union"]=>
    NULL
    ["withQueries"]=>
    NULL
    ["params"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["queryCacheDuration"]=>
    NULL
    ["queryCacheDependency"]=>
    NULL
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["where"]=>
    NULL
    ["limit"]=>
    NULL
    ["offset"]=>
    NULL
    ["orderBy"]=>
    NULL
    ["indexBy"]=>
    NULL
    ["emulateExecution"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["modelClass"]=>
    string(15) "app\models\Debt"
    ["with"]=>
    NULL
    ["asArray"]=>
    NULL
    ["multiple"]=>
    NULL
    ["primaryModel"]=>
    NULL
    ["link"]=>
    NULL
    ["via"]=>
    NULL
    ["inverseOf"]=>
    NULL
    ["viaMap":"yii\db\ActiveQuery":private]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["key"]=>
  NULL
  ["db"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
  ["_sort":"yii\data\BaseDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_pagination":"yii\data\BaseDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_keys":"yii\data\BaseDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_models":"yii\data\BaseDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_totalCount":"yii\data\BaseDataProvider":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_eventWildcards":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  NULL
}
```

The data is in the database, but I cannot get it from there

What could be the mistake?

Comment: $debtData is a model? or better, Debt::find() return a list of model? ->from(['debtData' => $debtData]) is not clear for me can you explain?

Comment: @Sfili_81, how can I find out it?

Comment: can you try printing the $dataprovider variable in the view file and comment the output here?

Comment: @KevinSunny, I print it, it says "object of class yii\data\ActiveDataProvider could not be converted to string"

Comment: I think the error is here :  `->from(['debtData' => $debtData]) ` debtData must be a string and debtData is an Object

Comment: @Sfili_81, $dataprovider is an object, but $debtData is NULL, if did gettype($debtData)

Comment: @Sfili_81, why it could be null here?

Comment: @АлександрСучков Meaning do a print_r or a var_dump! I know that it is an object. Want to know what is inside of it. Also see if you can print $debt_data and see if it has data.

Comment: @KevinSunny I edit my question with var_dump of $dataprovider

Comment: seems like the where clause is missing. You are using andwhere in line 10. Your debtdata query seems to be null.

Comment: @K3V debtdata query is null, you're right. You mean I need put where clause before andwhere?

Comment: @АлександрСучков I think that is the case. cant say more without more data. If you are finding it too difficult, ping me on twitter and I will try having a look at your deloyment.

Comment: @АлександрСучков Yes. You must start with where and then use andWhere. If you need: query-> where ('1 = 1')

Comment: @DanA.S. Thank for your answer. But if I change andWhere and start with Where, nothing changes.

Comment: @DanA.S. can you help me?

Comment: Sure! This is what I would do. First of all: Create your query outside of the Dataprovider. 2: Show your query (https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/857/show-raw-sql-query) and then run that query directly in MySqL. Do you get any results? Is the query wrong?